# End of the Ext functors

Tags: ct.category-theory, homological-algebra

Let $R$ be a ring, and consider the hom functor $\hom\colon Mod(R)^\text{op}\times Mod(R)\to Mod(R)$; the end of $\hom$ is well-known to be the set of endomorphisms (endonatural transformations) of the identity functor $1\colon Mod(R)\to Mod(R)$, i.e. the kernel
$$
\int_M \hom(M,M)\cong \ker\left(\prod_{M\in Mod(R)} \hom(M,M)\xrightarrow{(-)\circ \phi - \phi\circ(-)}
\prod_{\phi\colon M\to N}\hom(M,N)\right)
$$
Now, what should the end of the *derived* functors $Ext^n\colon Mod(R)^\text{op}\times Mod(R)\to Mod(R)$ be?

Comment: does it make sense to take the end of the derived Hom (ie the complex)? maybe it's given by the same formula but replacing ker with cone[-1]?

Comment: Please expand, if necessary in an answer, or follow me in chat :) no doubt that one could try to make precise that intuition, but bad things happen since resolutions are not canonical.

Comment: yeah, I don't really know what I'm talking about.

Comment: Let us denotes $D$ the category finitely projective $R$-modules. May be it will be helpful to notice that there is a quasi-isomorphism of chain complexes between $\mathbf{R}Hom(D,D)(id,id)$ and $HH(D)$ where $\mathbf{R}Hom(-,-)$ is the the derived internal hom in the category of DG-categories and $HH(D)\cong HH(R)$ is the Hochschild cochain complex associated to $D$ viewed as dg category in an obvious way. In my opinion, that should be the correct formulation in the derived world.

Comment: Another way of saying it:  Write $I: Mod(R) \to D(R)$ for the embedding into the derived category.  Then the end of $Ext^n$ should be the group of natural transformations $Nat(I,I[n])$.

Comment: Maybe you want $R$ to be commutative? Otherwise Hom won't be contained in $R$-modules. Or $R$ is any ring, and consider functors valued in abelian groups?

Comment: @Phil: Yes, this is because $$\int_M \mathrm{Ext}^n(M,M) = \int_M \mathrm{Hom}(I(M),I(M)[n]) = \mathrm{Hom}(I,I[n]).$$So the question is if there is any way to make this abelian group more explicit.