# Derived functors via coends, again

Tags: ct.category-theory, homological-algebra

Some time ago I [asked](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/203943/end-of-the-ext-functors) what the co/end of Ext/Tor functors was.

Now I want to play with the same items arranged in different ways: let's start from the fact that the composition maps
$$
\hom(A,X)\times \hom(X,B) \to \hom(A,B)
$$
form a cowedge in any category, and in fact a universal one, meaning that
$$
\hom(A,B) \cong \int^X\hom(A,X)\times \hom(X,B) 
$$
Is it possible to use a generalization of co/ends to "higher" co/ends (we have many) to regard $\text{Ext}^\bullet(X,Y)$ as , characterizing the whole complex, or its cochains, as a suitable coend? More explicitly, is it true that
$$
\text{Ext}^\bullet(X,Y) \cong \oint^A H_{X,Y}(A,A)
$$
for some flavour of higher co/end? And can we characterize 
$\text{Tor}_\bullet$ similarly?

A different (but possibly related) question is the following: is it possible to characterize the "old" definition for Ext (and also Yoneda higher Exts) using coends? The kind of quotient you define using "Baer sum" seems precisely induced by identifying two actions, on the left and on the right: given two exact sequences $A \xrightarrow{\phi} E\to B$ and $A\xrightarrow{\gamma} F\to B$ then $\text{Ext}^1(B,A)$ is defined as $(E\oplus_B F)/\simeq$, where $\simeq$ is the equivalence relation induced by $(\phi(a)+e,f) \simeq (e, \gamma(a)+f)$